# Battery Charger design

Tags: power-supply, batteries, raspberry-pi, lithium-ion, ups

In my new project i need to use a battery back up for the raspberry pi.But it will not interfere the operation of pi.
In my last design i used ACT2813 for my battery management application, but when main power fails it takes 2sec to deliver the power to the load. At this time the pi will off and then start.
Can anyone suggest a battery charger and power path management circuit for 2400mAH Li-ion battery.(just like a ups)

Comment: Add schematic. Fix language.

Comment: What is max load current? More details on mains power supply iwill be useful. More detail, less to& fro, better answers

Comment: Maximum load current will be about 2.5A, it should work from 5v regulated power supply.

Answer (score 2):

I power my Raspberry Pi via its USB connector. I simply use a portable USB phone charger battery bank inserted between the Pi and a wall adapter. The wall adapter normally charges the battery bank and powers the Pi. When the power fails, the USB battery bank takes over. Simple and inexpensive.